# Making a snippet from a Markdown article

Tags: markdown

Is there a good way to take content from a Markdown article and make a snippet (for example, something to show in search results)?

If you take an article written like this:

```
#Welcome!
This is a  *large* amount of markdown _symbols_. 
Here are some other things that are possible in markdown:
* Lists
* using
* an asterisk
```

and just output the non-formatted markdown, you'll get a lot of hashes and undesrscores in your snippet. It looks terrible.

```
> #Welcome! This is a  *large* amount of markdown _symbols_    Here are some other things that are possible in markdown:    * Lists    * using
> * an asterisk
```

Is there a common practice for how to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

pandoc converts to several [outputformats](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#general-options).

The format 'plain' strips strong and em, but leaves blocks like headings and listings. Is acceptable?

```
$ pandoc --to plain Welcome.md
Welcome!
========

This is a large amount of markdown symbols. Here are some other things
that are possible in markdown:

-   Lists
-   using
-   an asterisk
```

Unfortunately 'plain' is not supported by the [pandoc dingus](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/try/)